# leftbars seem to be a little left shifted

Tags: html, css

I was working on leftbars for my website but they seem to be a little left shifted. I don't know why this happens. I have attached the code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main_element">
    <div id="first-child">
        <img/><span id="edit">Edit Picture</span>
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar" align="center">
        <div>Left bar 1</div>
        <div>Left bar 2</div>
        <div>Left bar 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main_element{
width:90%;
position:relative;
border:1px solid teal;
}

#first-child{
position:relative;
height:90%;
width:100%;
}

#edit{
position:absolute;
right:6%;
top:4%;
font-size:1em;
}

#main_element #first-child img{
border:1px solid teal;
height:50%;
width:90%;
margin:5%;
background-color:#ccc;
}

#leftbar{
height:40%;
margin:0 1%;
}

#leftbar div{
border:1px solid;
width:100%;
height:25%;
background:#E0E0E0;
text-align:center;
padding:1% 0;
}
```

I am attaching a demo too. http://jsbin.com/agahuw/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have their width at 100% but you have also added a border to them, this means the actual width is 100% + 2px

If you need to have a border on them, don't give them a width - they should fill their container by default (unless you float them)

Comment: You can also set `box-sizing: border-box` and keep the borders. (Includes borders when calculating the size of the box)